# Scriptural reference of Prabhupada's commentry on S.B. 4:19:11

Tags: bhagavata-purana, sacrifice, ashwamedha, iskcon

Srila Prabhupada wrote in the [purport](https://prabhupadabooks.com/sb/4/19/11) of S.B. 4:19:11,

> King Indra is known as śata-kratu, which indicates that he has performed one hundred horse sacrifices (aśvamedha-yajña). We should know, however, that the animals sacrificed in the yajña were not killed. If the Vedic mantras were properly pronounced during the sacrifice, **the animal sacrificed would come out again with a new life.”**

Is there any scriptural refrence regarding this point that sacrificed animal can come back to life if mantras are chanted rightly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any scriptural refrence regarding this point that sacrificed animal can come back to life if mantras are chanted rightly?

This can't be possible because there are actually mantras from the veda samhitas uttered in the animal sacrifice and addressed to the sacrificial animal that explicitly wish the animal a speedy journey to swarga after it's killed:

> na vA uve tan mriyase na riShyasi | devAgm ideShi pathibhis sugebhiH | yatra yanti sukRto nApi duShkRtaH | tatra tvA devas savitA dadhAtu |
>
> You do not die, nor do you get injured. You go to the gods through easy paths where people who do good go and not those who do evil. May the god SavitA take you there.

If the atma of the animal goes to swarga, then it won't get resurrected back into its body.

There is another mantra found in the ashvamedha section of the Taittiriya Brahmana:

> yamalokam evainam gamayati
>
> He (the priest) sends him (the atma of the sacrificed horse) to Yama's realm.

Also from the Manusmriti:

> [5.40](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200417.html) - Herbs, animals, trees, beasts, and birds, reaching death for the sake of sacrifices, attain advancements.

Medhatithi's commentary:

> But when an animal is killed at a sacrifice, this killing becomes a great benefit conferred upon it, and it is not an injury because it does not lead it to hell or any such undesirable conditions. That this is so follows from the fact that those ‘reaching death’— destruction—at a sacrifice —‘attain advancements’—higher positions, in regard to caste and so forth;—being born as a God or a Gandharva, or as men born in better countries or continents—such as the Uttarakuru and the like.

So it's clear that the animal sacrificed doesn't return to it's body. Plus, logically it wouldn't make sense, because then that would not be an *animal sacrifice*.

Comment: Brilliant answer. If possible please try to add the specific verse numbers also to the Veda Mantras.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually based on the concept that:
We are not this body but we are sprit soul.

So when the sacrificial animal is sacrificed, the sages due to high consciousness and power obtained from tapasya and austerities, had the power to remove the soul from one body while sacrificing the old body and gifted the soul of the sacrificial animal a new body of the same animal it previously was. So this way, a sacrifice was made such that it looked like the animal was killed and brought alive while it was actually just given a new body and the old one in which it housed previously was sacrificed. So actually no Actual killing took place.

Hare Krishna

Comment: Give scriptural references. This type of answers are not acceptable in HSE.